# Bombs Away Battleships

Tags: java, python, google-maps

```
print("----BATTLESHIPS 3.0 By NAME----")
print("")
print("")

size = input("Map size: ")
size = size.replace(" ", "")
print("------")

keys = {1:'A',2:'B',3:'C',4:'D',5:'E',6:'F',7:'G',8:'H',9:'I',10:'J',11:'K',12:'L',13:'M',14:'N',15:'O',16:'P',17:'Q',18:'R',19:'S',20:'T',21:'U',22:'V',23:'W',24:'X',25:'Y',26:'Z'}

#COORDINATES
for h in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
  for b in range(1, int(size) + 1): 
    num = [h, b]
    #print(num, end=' ')
#COORDINATES

dict = {}
guess = input("Guess: ")
guess = guess.lower()
guess = guess.replace(" ", "")
print("---")

while guess:

  if guess in dict:
    print("Whoops! You've already hit that coordinate") 

  elif guess not in num:
    print("Woah! That isn't a square!")

  #elif int(guess[1:]) > 10 and int(guess[1:]) >= 1:
    #print("Woah! That isn't a square!")

  else:
    dict[guess]=guess
    print("Hit", guess.upper())

  guess = input("Guess: ")
  guess = guess.lower()
  guess = guess.replace(" ", "")
  print("---")

yn = input("List your guesses? (yes or no)")
yn = yn.lower()

if yn == "yes":

  print("------")
  print("GUESSES:")

  print("---")
  for i in dict:
    print("-", i.upper()) 

elif yn == "no":
  print("Ok, bye!")
else:
  print("---")
  print("Please don't try and trick me. No scores for you!")
```

I am having a lot of trouble with this. I am supposed to create a program that extends a simple program called Bomb's Away. I am trying to limit the size of the map but not doing a very good job. Everything I input says it is not a square.

**Image of my problem:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0DAC.png

**Requirements:**

Bombs Away is based on the Battleship Game where two players guess positions on a map. Each position on the map is identified by a Letter-Number location. In the original problem, the program recorded every position the player typed. If the coordinate was already recorded the program said so.

- The user is allowed to set the size of the map. The map is always square. The map cannot exceed the number of characters found in our alphabet (i.e. 26 characters). The smallest size for the map is 5 columns. The program prompts the user to provide the size of the map.
- When entering the size of the map, the program ensures that a valid number has been input. If not the user is presented with a message to input a valid number. The user cannot continue until an acceptable number is input.
- If the user types in valid coordinates, the program stores that information. Design a creative approach to presenting the user that the coordinates have been recorded.
- If the user types in coordinates that don’t exist, creatively present the user a message of this. These coordinates must not be stored. Only valid coordinates are stored.

Comment: Have you tried printing `num`? You'll see it is lacking in coordinates somewhat.

Comment: I have, but I don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep re-binding `num` to a new list object, one with just the current `h` and `b` values:

```
for h in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
    for b in range(1, int(size) + 1): 
        num = [h, b]
```

In the end, if you entered `10` for the size, you get `num = ['Z', 10]`. No coordinate the user is entering is going to be part of that list.

You need to set `num` to an empty list and *append* new coordinates, where you have concatenated the `h` and `b` values into a new string first:

```
num = []
for h in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
    for b in range(1, int(size) + 1): 
        num.append(h + str(b))
```

You could use more compact Python code to produce the same results; using a list comprehension and string formatting:

```
num = ['{}{}'.format(h, b + 1) 
       for h in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" for b in range(int(size))]
```

You probably want to limit the height as well as the breadth of the map, so you'll need to limit the number of letters used; you could slice those by the size:

```
num = []
size = int(size)
for h in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[:size]:
    for b in range(1, size + 1):
        num.append(h + str(b))
```

Do note that `size` should always be entered as a number *only*!

Comment: Now I am getting an error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 17, in <module>
    for b in range(1, int(size) + 1): 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A1'

Comment: @Matt: so why did you enter `A1` for the size of the map?

Comment: @Matt: did you print `num` again? What does it contain now?

Comment: @Martjin Pieters ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10'] ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B9', 'B10'] ['A1', 'A2', 'A...... and it continues

Comment: @Matt: looks like you are printing `num` in the outer loop, repeatedly. Move he `print` call *out* of the loop and print just once.

Comment: I discovered the problem. I was trying to check if the lower case guess was in the upper case list. In the end I changed the guess to upper case instead of lower.